# Отправка аттача с формы Tilda на почту

Tags: php

Есть форма на тильде, [ссылка на форму][1], к ней надо подсоединить свой скрипт php. Скрипт пишу при помощи phpmail(желание заказчика). В форму передается также вложение. Но при попытке передать это вложение в письмо на почту - получается фейл. При попытке узнать что приходит на форму - получаю следующее:

```
[name] => uhkuhnuk
[adress] => вымыф
[phone] => 8+95656566
[name_f] => 4513454
[shop] => Днепр, ул. Сечевых Стрельцов, 89-Б (ул. Артёма)
[tovar] => ыуацыуац
[master] => Мастерами Двери Белоруссии
[install_w] => Мастерами Двери Белоруссии
[brak] => уацуа
[file] => upwidget-341c9085868dcc94c922e4237e95f96e/karta-ukraini-dlya-ditej_tilda21977.jpg
[select] => 3. Вызвать реставратора (при мелком браке)
```

где [file] - элемент массива $_POST, а именно то самое поле в форме где я делаю аттач. Ссылка в нем пишется неправильная, получить по ней файл у меня не выходит.
а `var_dump($_FILES); print_r($_FILES);`
то есть массив $_FILES приходит пустой, соответсвенно `move_uploaded_file();` и другие похожие функции не работают. Подскажите как можно получить вложение с этой формы?
Форма и скрипт на разных хостах.....

Код формы могу только с отладчика вытянуть, в Тильде нет прямого доступа к ее исходникам

```html
<form id="form65631891" name='form65631891' role="form" action='http://zayavlenie.com.ua/mail3.php' method='POST' data-formactiontype="1" data-inputbox=".t-input-group" class="t-form js-form-proccess t-form_inputs-total_11 " data-success-callback="t678_onSuccess">
    <!-- NO ONE SERVICES CONNECTED -->
    <div class="js-successbox t-form__successbox t-text t-text_md" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="t-form__inputsbox">
        <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_nm" data-input-lid="1493283059688">
            <div class="t-input-block">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="t-input js-tilda-rule " value="" placeholder="Ваше ФИО" data-tilda-req="1" data-tilda-rule="name" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8; ">
                <div class="t-input-error"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_in" data-input-lid="1494858943227">
            <div class="t-input-block">
                <input type="text" name="adress" class="t-input js-tilda-rule " value="" placeholder="Ваш адрес, куда доставляли двери" data-tilda-req="1" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8; ">
                <div class="t-input-error"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_ph" data-input-lid="1495040492013">
            <div class="t-input-block">
                <input type="text" name="phone" class="t-input js-tilda-rule " value="" placeholder="Ваш телефон" data-tilda-req="1" data-tilda-rule="phone" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8; ">
                <div class="t-input-error"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_in" data-input-lid="1495027254430">
            <div class="t-input-title t-descr t-descr_md" data-redactor-toolbar="no" field="li_title__1495027254430" style="">№ счёт-фактуры и дата</div>
            <div class="t-input-block">
                <input type="text" name="name_f" class="t-input js-tilda-rule " value="" placeholder="например: ДБ 000001450 от 03.08.2018" data-tilda-req="1" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8; ">
                <div class="t-input-error"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_sb" data-input-lid="1536061279873">
        <div class="t-input-title t-descr t-descr_md" data-redactor-toolbar="no" field="li_title__1536061279873" style="">Магазин</div>
        <div class="t-input-subtitle t-descr t-descr_xxs t-opacity_70" data-redactor-toolbar="no" field="li_subtitle__1536061279873" style="">Выберите магазин, в котором Вы оформляли заказ</div>
        <div class="t-input-block">
            <div class="t-select__wrapper ">
                <select name="shop" class="t-select js-tilda-rule " data-tilda-req="1" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8; ">
                    <option value="">Выберите вариант из списка...</option>
                    <option value="Киев, пр. Победы, 17">Киев, пр. Победы, 17</option>
                    <option value="Киев, ул. Большая Васильковская, 145/1">Киев, ул. Большая Васильковская, 145/1</option>
                    <option value="Киев, Демеевская площадь, пр. В. Лобановского">Киев, Демеевская площадь, пр. В. Лобановского</option>
                    <option value="Киев, ул. Кольцевая, 2">Киев, ул. Кольцевая, 2</option>
                    <option value="Киев, ул. Марины Цветаевой, 13">Киев, ул. Марины Цветаевой, 13</option>
                    <option value="Киев, ул. Днепровская Набережная, 26-Д">Киев, ул. Днепровская Набережная, 26-Д</option>
                    <option value="Киев, пр. Голосеевский, 128">Киев, пр. Голосеевский, 128</option>
                    <option value="Киев, бул. Чоколовский, 9/13">Киев, бул. Чоколовский, 9/13</option>
                    <option value="Киев, ул. Харьковское Шоссе, 2 ">Киев, ул. Харьковское Шоссе, 2 </option>
                    <option value="Киев, пр. Героев Сталинграда, 6">Киев, пр. Героев Сталинграда, 6</option>
                    <option value="Львов, ул. Научная, 49-А">Львов, ул. Научная, 49-А</option>
                    <option value="Львов, ул. Липинского, 28 (Парус)">Львов, ул. Липинского, 28 (Парус)</option>
                    <option value="Львов, ул. Городоцкая, 209">Львов, ул. Городоцкая, 209</option>
                    <option value="Днепр, ул. Литейная, 17-А">Днепр, ул. Литейная, 17-А</option>
                    <option value="Днепр, пр. Гагарина, 99">Днепр, пр. Гагарина, 99</option>
                    <option value="Днепр, ул. Сечевых Стрельцов, 89-Б (ул. Артёма)">Днепр, ул. Сечевых Стрельцов, 89-Б (ул. Артёма)</option>
                    <option value="Днепр, пр. Слобожанский, 107 (им. Газеты Правда)">Днепр, пр. Слобожанский, 107 (им. Газеты Правда)</option>
                    <option value="Одесса, пр. Небесной Сотни, 3-А (пр. Маршала Жукова) ">Одесса, пр. Небесной Сотни, 3-А (пр. Маршала Жукова) </option>
                    <option value="Одесса, ул. Николаевская дорога, 223/225">Одесса, ул. Николаевская дорога, 223/225</option>
                    <option value="Одесса, ул. Малая Арнаутская, 92">Одесса, ул. Малая Арнаутская, 92</option>
                    <option value="Харьков, пр. Гагарина, 21">Харьков, пр. Гагарина, 21</option>
                    <option value="Харьков, ул. Героев Труда, 46">Харьков, ул. Героев Труда, 46</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="t-input-error"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_ta" data-input-lid="1536066181960">
        <div class="t-input-title t-descr t-descr_md" data-redactor-toolbar="no" field="li_title__1536066181960" style="">Название товара</div>
        <div class="t-input-subtitle t-descr t-descr_xxs t-opacity_70" data-redactor-toolbar="no" field="li_subtitle__1536066181960" style="">Введите название двери или фурнитуры, по которому Вы хотите произвести обмен или возврат.</div>
        <div class="t-input-block">
            <textarea name="tovar" class="t-input js-tilda-rule " placeholder="Например: Вена орех ПО" data-tilda-req="1" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8; height:68px" rows="2"></textarea>
            <div class="t-input-error"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_sb" data-input-lid="1536066643939">
        <div class="t-input-title t-descr t-descr_md" data-redactor-toolbar="no" field="li_title__1536066643939" style="">Кем был произведен замер?</div>
            <div class="t-input-block">
                <div class="t-select__wrapper ">
                    <select name="master" class="t-select js-tilda-rule " data-tilda-req="1" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8; ">
                        <option value="">Выберите вариант из списка...</option>
                        <option value="Мастерами Двери Белоруссии">Мастерами Двери Белоруссии</option>
                        <option value="У меня был свой мастер">У меня был свой мастер</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="t-input-error"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_sb" data-input-lid="1536066915125">
            <div class="t-input-title t-descr t-descr_md" data-redactor-toolbar="no" field="li_title__1536066915125" style="">Кем была произведена установка?</div>
            <div class="t-input-block">
                <div class="t-select__wrapper ">
                    <select name="install_w" class="t-select js-tilda-rule " data-tilda-req="1" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8; ">
                        <option value="">Выберите вариант из списка...</option>
                        <option value="Мастерами Двери Белоруссии">Мастерами Двери Белоруссии</option>
                        <option value="У меня был свой мастер">У меня был свой мастер</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="t-input-error"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_ta" data-input-lid="1536066982770">
            <div class="t-input-block">
                <textarea name="brak" class="t-input js-tilda-rule " placeholder="Опишите Ваш брак или причину замены " data-tilda-req="1" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8; height:102px" rows="3"></textarea>
                <div class="t-input-error"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_uw" data-input-lid="1536068049577">
            <div class="t-input-title t-descr t-descr_md" data-redactor-toolbar="no" field="li_title__1536068049577" style="">Загрузить фото</div>
            <div class="t-input-block">
                <div class="t-upwidget" style='margin-bottom:10px;'>
                    <input type="text" type="hidden" role="upwidget-uploader" class="js-tilda-rule" name="file" data-tilda-upwidget-key="google-ab0dfd527e1afae4b95d491" data-tilda-upwidget-multiple="1" style="display:none;">
                    <script src='https://upwidget.tildacdn.com/js/tilda-upwidget-1.1.min.js' async></script>
                </div>
                <div class="t-input-error"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_sb" data-input-lid="1536068168958">
            <div class="t-input-title t-descr t-descr_md" data-redactor-toolbar="no" field="li_title__1536068168958" style="">Выберите подходящие решение </div>
            <div class="t-input-block">
                <div class="t-select__wrapper ">
                    <select name="select" class="t-select js-tilda-rule " data-tilda-req="1" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8; ">
                        <option value="1. Замена товара (при браке товара или если товар Вам не подошел)">1. Замена товара (при браке товара или если товар Вам не подошел)</option>
                        <option value="2. Возврат средств (при браке товара)">2. Возврат средств (при браке товара)</option>
                        <option value="3. Вызвать реставратора (при мелком браке)">3. Вызвать реставратора (при мелком браке)</option>
                        <option value="4. Вызвать установщика (при браке установки)">4. Вызвать установщика (при браке установки)</option>
                        <option value="5. Узнать у менеджера (узнать подходящий для меня вариант)">5. Узнать у менеджера (узнать подходящий для меня вариант)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="t-input-error"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="t-form__errorbox-middle">
            <div class="js-errorbox-all t-form__errorbox-wrapper" style="display:none;">
                <div class="t-form__errorbox-text t-text t-text_md">
                    <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-all"></p>
                    <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-req"></p>
                    <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-email"></p>
                    <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-name"></p>
                    <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-phone"></p>
                    <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-string"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="t-form__submit">
            <button type="submit" class="t-submit" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#000000;">ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВЛЕНИЕ</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="t-form__errorbox-bottom">
        <div class="js-errorbox-all t-form__errorbox-wrapper" style="display:none;">
            <div class="t-form__errorbox-text t-text t-text_md">
                <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-all"></p>
                <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-req"></p>
                <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-email"></p>
                <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-name"></p>
                <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-phone"></p>
                <p class="t-form__errorbox-item js-rule-error js-rule-error-string"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Код формы покажите.

Comment: Код формы нормально добавить не могу, у Тильды нет доступа к ее исходникам... Конструктор гребанный

Comment: Оформите код формы как полагается. Ни у кого нет желания читать однострочную портянку

Comment: В форме нет `enctype` аттрибута. Если же данные шлются аяксом - то для отправки контента файла просто сериализации недостаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Помог комментарий пользователя @u_mulder. Добавил свою форму с учетом `enctype`, теперь в массив `$_FILES` данные приходят.